# wireguard Invalid manifest

Tags: manifest, wireguard

I try to build a vpn with wireguard as open server. and then I try to inject the dependency of wireguard, the error is raised as showed in image below:

**Screenshot**
[image]

I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue. It was because of the swift tools version  compatibility issue. Try to add lower version of WiregGurdKit through SPM. Verion "1.0.15-26" worked for me. To get list of older versions check  https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-apple.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this error. To solve it, you should:

1. Clone the repository (https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-apple) to a local "wireguard-apple" directory
2. Edit your local package's "Package.Swift" first line from "// swift-tools-version:5.3" to "// swift-tools-version:5.5"
3. Perform the WireGuardKit integration as per the guide in "README.md"

You will likely encounter other errors afterwards related to "/usr/bin/make". In step 2, specifically in the instruction `'In the appeared "Info" tab of a newly created target, type in the "Directory" path under the "External Build Tool Configuration"'`, make sure to browse to the folder where you have your MAKE file. Furthermore, you also need to download go@1.19 and add a user-defined variable in XCode called "PATH", with value "${PATH}:/path/to/go@1.19/bin".

Hope this helps!

Comment: For me issue wasn't related to build tool. Instead, provided external build tool configuration directory could not find makefile (on Xcode 14.2 or 14.3 `${BUILD_DIR%Build/*}` was making it ignore the directory value altogether) if you are adding library locally clone it in directory with **.xcodeproj* and change path to `$PROJECT_DIR/wireguard-apple/Sources/WireGuardKitGo`. You can also add package of prior version (set dependency rule to *1.0.5-26*) and for external build tool configuration directory path use `$BUILD_DIR/../../SourcePackages/checkouts/wireguard-apple/Sources/WireGuardKitGo`.